# Cannot convert value of type '(Store).Type' to expected argument type 'Binding<C>'

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to add items to an array in 1 view and then show that array in another view using a foreach loop but I keep getting these errors

```
Cannot convert value of type '(Store).Type' to expected argument type 'Binding<C>'
```

and `Generic parameter 'C' could not be inferred`

Here is my class  - import SwiftUI

```
class StoreViewModel: ObservableObject{
    
    @Published var item: [String] = []
    @Published var amount: [String] = []

}
```

and here is where I try to show the items added

```
import SwiftUI

struct Store: View {
    
    @State var presented: Bool = false
    @State var showingAlert:Bool = false
    @StateObject var store = StoreViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView{
            VStack{
                HStack{
                    Button {
                        
                        showingAlert = true
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "trash")
                            .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                            .font(.system(size: 20))
                    }
                    .alert("Are you sure you want to remove all items", isPresented: $showingAlert) {
                                Button("OK", role: .destructive) {
                                    withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: 0.3)){
                                     
                                    }
                                    
                                }
                    }

                    Text("Your Cupboard")
                        .font(.system(size: 30))
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        .padding()
                    Spacer()
                    Button {
                        presented.toggle()
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                            .font(.system(size: 30))
                            .foregroundColor(Color(hex: "FF0044"))
                    }
                    .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $presented, content: AddItem.init)

                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
                Text("Here you can see what you have in your cupboard")
                    .padding()
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                Text("Click the + to add an item")
                    .padding()
                ForEach((Store), id: \.self){item in
                    HStack{
                        Spacer()
                        Text(item)
                            .font(.system(size: 20))
                        Text("30g")
                        Spacer()
                        Button {

                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "trash")
                                .foregroundColor(.red)
                                .font(.system(size: 15))
                        }
                        .padding(.trailing)
                    }
                    .padding()

                }
            }
        }
        .environmentObject(store)
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I overcome my errors?
Many Thanks for your time and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case sensitivity matters. You mean `store`, the `StoreViewModel` instance and not the type of `self`. Further the purpose of a `ForEach` expression is to iterate an array (presumably `item(s)`).

First of all to avoid more confusion rename `item` in `StoreViewModel` as its plural form

```
class StoreViewModel: ObservableObject{
    
    @Published var items: [String] = []
    @Published var amount: [String] = []

}
```

Then replace

```
ForEach((Store), id: \.self){ item in
```

with

```
ForEach(store.items, id: \.self){ item in
```